# Split string input from textbox and convert it to array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to get the input from a textbox and convert it to string in order to find the longest word using:

```
string longest = stringArray.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

For instance I have input in a text box "My sisters lives in UK"
I want to have it in an array like ["My" , "sister", "lives", "in", "UK"] in order to use the code above to find the longest string.
Thanks

Comment: You have to use split first on string , that will return you `stringArray`, `string longest = "My sisters lives in UK".Split().OrderByDescending(s=> s.Length).First();`

Comment: Can I include "," ":" as well in case the user use puncture instead of blank spaces?

Comment: @Ravanliyski yes just use `.Split(new[]{',', ':', ' '})`

Comment: sure you can, in that case pass `"yourstring".Split(',',':',';',' ')`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to split the textbox value by a space:

```
string[] stringArray = textBox.Text.Split(' ');
string longest = stringArray.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s= "This is test";
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
var sorted=words.OrderBy(n => n.Length);
var longest = sorted.LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] stringArray = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[]{' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: There is no comma in original string `"My sisters lives in UK" `